# Conflicto al validar una password con jqueryvalidation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Siguiendo los consejos de un colaborador de esta página web, decidí incluir el plugin de [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Ahora bien, estuve siguiendo un tutorial subido por los propios desarrolladores del plugin, donde implementan una función que llaman strongPaswword. En ella hacen lo siguiente:

```
$.validator.addMethod('strongPassword', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.length >= 6 && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
}, 'La contraseña debe tener por lo menos 6 caracteres y debe contener al menos un número y un caracter')
```

Pero algo esta mal porque el me cansé de poner cadenas del tipo "abcdef1$" etc etc etc que no funciona !!!
Me gustó mucho el plugin y me gustaría poder terminar de implementarlo, pero bueno, encontré una barrera en este punto... 
alguien podrá darme una mano ?

[Aquí el link del video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TehnRqQtKv8)

[image: ven el error ?]

ven el error ? cambie el campo de tipo password a formato texto para que vean que pongo mas de seis caracteres y un numero y el plugin no me valida la strongPassword

SIGUE EL ERROR, no he podido resolverlo...

Comment: Agrega el error, comportamiento, o lo que sea la barrrera que tienes; será de utilidad a quien sepa del tema. Incluye información que aporte más detalle de que ocurre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es un ejemplo del plugin con tres elementos a validar, espero te sea de utilidad, todo esta comentado para cualquier duda

```js
//importante para iniciar 
$(function () {
   //Valida solo letras en el campo asignado
    $.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]*$/i.test(value);
    }, "Solo letras");
//Hace la validación del password, debe ser de la siguiente forma abcde1, a#1234, etc
    $.validator.addMethod('strongPassword', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value.length >= 6 && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
    }, 'La contraseña debe tener por lo menos 6 caracteres y debe contener al menos un número y un caracter')
    //Formulario a validar
    $(".signup-form").validate({
       //Clases asignadas para el error y cuando son validas
        errorClass: "error-class",
        validClass: "valid-class",
        //Reglas
        rules: {
        //El campo con name = "fullname" es requerido y se aplica la validación de solo letras
            fullname: {
                required: true,
                lettersonly: true
            },
            //El campo con name ="email" es requerido y se aplica la validación por defecto de email
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            //El campo con name ="pass" es requerido y se aplica la validación strongPassword
            pass: {
                required: true,
                strongPassword: true
            },
            //El campo con name ="confirm_password" es requerido y se aplica la validación strongPassword y tiene que ser igual al campo con id="pass"
            confirm_password: {
     required: true,
          strongPassword: true,
     equalTo: "#pass"
   },

        },
        //Mensajes en caso de error
        messages: {
       //Campo con name fullname, si no contiene ningun elemento
         fullname:{
          required: "Ingresa nombre"
         },
          //Campo con name pass, si no contiene ningun elemento
            pass: {
                required: "Ingresa nueva contraseña."
            },
            //Campo con name confirm_password, si no contiene ningun elemento
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Reingresa la contraseña."
            },
            //Campo con name email, si no contiene ningun elemento
            email: {
                required: "Ingresa Correo electrónico.",
                minlength: "Correo incorrecto"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

```css
  .user_signup input[type="text"].error-class,
.user_signup input[type="email"].error-class,
.user_signup input[type="password"].error-class {
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: red;
}

.user_signup input.valid-class {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    color: black;
}

.user_signup label.error-class {

    color:red; margin-top:-20px; 
}

.user_signup {
    display: block;
}

.user_signup label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    color:#666;
}

.user_signup input[type="text"], .user_signup input[type="email"], .user_signup input[type="password"] {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1.2px solid #DDD;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#333;
    font-family:arial;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.user_signup input[type="password"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F;
}

.user_signup input[type="text"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F;
}

.user_signup input[type="email"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F;
}

.signupbtn {
    background: #F4F4F2;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0px 0;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top:15px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    border:none;
}

/*.btn_red {background:orange; color: #FFF; }*/
 .signupbtn:hover {
    background:blue;
    color:white;
}

.btnwrapper2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.signup-form {
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.signup-form p {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-size:20px;
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="user_signup" id="user_register1">
    <form class="signup-form">
        <input class="fullname errorClass" type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="First and Last Name" />
        <input class="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" />
        <input id="pass" class="pass" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="New password" />
        <input class="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password" placeholder="New password" />
        <div class="btnwrapper2">
            <input class="signupbtn" value="Sign up!" type="submit" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias !!! voy a compararlo con lo que hice yo para ver en qué parte me fallaba el codigo... por lo que veo está igual. Gracias nuevamente